# DisplayTool installation and usage

Tags: maven, velocity

I am using Velocity 1.7 to format string and I had some trouble with default values. Velocity by itself has no special syntax for case when value is not set and we want to use some another, default value. 
By the means of Velocity it looks like:

```
#if(!${name})Default John#else${name}#end
```

which is unconveniant for my case.
After googling I've found DisplayTool, according to documentation it will look like:

```
$display.alt($name,"Default John")
```

So I added maven dependency but not sure how to add DisplayTool to my method and it is hard to found instructions for this.
Maybe somebody can help with advice or give useful links?..

My method:

```
public String testVelocity(String url) throws Exception{

    Velocity.init();
    VelocityContext context = getVelocityContext();//gets simple VelocityContext object 
    Writer out = new StringWriter();
    Velocity.evaluate(context, out, "testing", url);

    logger.info("got first results "+out);

    return out.toString();
}
```

When I send

```
String url = "http://www.test.com?withDefault=$display.alt(\"not null\",\"exampleDefaults\")&truncate=$display.truncate(\"This is a long string.\", 10)";
String result = testVelocity(url);
```

I get "http://www.test.com?withDefault=$display.alt(\"not null\",\"exampleDefaults\")&truncate=$display.truncate(\"This is a long string.\", 10)" without changes, but should get

```
"http://www.test.com?withDefault=not null&truncate=This is...
```

Please tell me what I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of the URL occurs in your Java code, before you invoke Velocity, so Velocity isn't going to evaluate `$display.alt(\"not null\",\"exampleDefaults\")`.  That syntax will be valid only in a Velocity template (which typically have `.vm` extensions).

In the Java code, there's no need to use the `$` notation, you can just call the DisplayTool methods directly.  I've not worked with `DisplayTool` before, but it's probably something like this:

```
DisplayTool display = new DisplayTool();
String withDefault = display.alt("not null","exampleDefaults");
String truncate = display.truncate("This is a long string.", 10);
String url = "http://www.test.com?" 
    + withDefault=" + withDefault 
    + "&truncate=" + truncate;
```

It might be better, though,  to call your `DisplayTool` methods directly from the Velocity template.  That's what is shown in the [example usage](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DisplayTool.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for something to give me conveniant tool to format only strings, without using templates. And when receiving the string I don't know where exactly will be located reference and what is the default value for it. Everything should be set in string by special expression. I've thought that Display Tool provides this. It's a pity that it doesn't. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @me1111 Have a look at the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class in Apache Commons Lang, particularly the `defaultString` and `defaultEmpty` methods.

Comment: Thanks, but if I will use standard methods of java there is no reason to use Velocity then. I was told to research what means faster and more comfortable. Found one more tool that I think can replace Velocity - Freemarker, for defaults it has smth like unsafe_expr!default_expr. Thank you for your time.